# Can't trigger action after changing element's ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a show/hide password button, when I click to SHOW the password, it works, but when I try to hide it again it doesn't.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vcvgj09z/

```
<input type="password" id="pass1" value="Now try to hide me">
<a href="#" id="show-password"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Show</a>

    $("#show-password").on("click",function() {
        $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i> Hide');
        $(this).prop("id","hide-password");
        $("#pass1").attr("type","text");
    });
    $("#hide-password").on("click",function() {
        $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Show');
        $(this).prop("id","show-password");
        $("#pass1").attr("type","password");
    });
```

Comment: Don't change the ID of an element...

Comment: Tried remove/addClass too :(

Comment: The click events in your code are bound upon runtime — and at runtime the element `#hide-password` is not present.

Comment: The right approach here is to not change an element's ID. If you're doing styling, use classes.

Comment: All right guys, thanks a lot. I'll change it to class instead of ID, using the "body".on("click" ..) as rfornal suggested - Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my comment, the reason why your code is not working is because the element `#hide-password` is not present in the DOM at runtime, so **no click events will be bound to it**.

Although you can use `.on()` to listen to event bubbling, I strongly advise against changing IDs of elements. Instead, you can store the toggle on/off state as a jQuery `data` object. The advantages of this method is that:

- does not rely on changing the markup and event bubbling
- stores the toggle state of the password by evaluating and modifying the jQuery `data` object
- allows other elements to manipulate/influence the toggle state

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/vcvgj09z/10/

```
$('#toggle-password').click(function() {
    // Check state
    if(!$(this).data('state') || $(this).data('state') == 0) {
        // If the data object "state" is undefined or have a value of 0, convert password to text
        // Update HTML and data object
        $(this)
        .html('<i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i> Hide')
        .data('state', 1);

        // Change password to text
        $("#pass1").attr('type', 'text');   
    } else {
        // If the data object "state" has a value of 1, convert text to password
        // Update HTML and data object
        $(this)
        .html('<i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Show')
        .data('state', 0);

        // Change text to password
        $("#pass1").attr("type","password");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge Terry! Very instructive indeed

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this ...

```
$("body").on("click", "#show-password", function() {
```

... and associated ...

```
$("body").on("click", "#hide-password", function() {
```

This way when the ID dynamically changes, the on-click's will work.

Comment: Thanks buddy, it worked. I understood why it wasn't working, it was as Terry said.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesnt work because it does not support the dynamically setted elements.

The correct way to set the events for dynamically added elements is by using `$(document).on()`.

JS:

```
$(document).on("click", "#show-password", function() {
    $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i> Hide');
    $(this).prop("id","hide-password");
    $("#pass1").attr("type","text");
});

$(document).on("click", "#hide-password", function() {
    $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Show');
    $(this).prop("id","show-password");
    $("#pass1").attr("type","password");
});
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/vcvgj09z/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use delegate. Because you generated new DOM

```
 $(document).on("click","#show-password",function() {
    //....
 });
 $(document).on("click","#hide-password",function() {
    //....
 });
```